# How do I change dovecot's imap and pop 'banner'?

Tags: dovecot

How do I change dovecot's imap and pop 'banner'?

When I do a telnet to my server using:

```
me@my-server:~# telnet localhost 143
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.
```

How can I change `Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready` to `My Mail System Creative Name ready`?

If any of you guys wonder why, I usually do not want to be targeted by any attacks that exist for particular mail softwares, so I feel like hiding their name.

And also, why am I using port 143 for this example? I think telnet is unable to handle SSL/TLS, so I get this if I ping port 993, but everything is working properly though, if you are wondering:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

And for POP, I get this, almost forgot the mention:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.
```

And I want to change `Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.` to `My Creative Mail System Name ready.`, or to something more meaningful than my creative name.

Comment: Such attacks are mostly done by bots, and they don't care if you try elementary tricks like this. They will just try breaking in with all known exploits anyway. There is little point to trying to change this banner.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, but why not help me do it? I have some personal opinions. Hmm... I think I should download the dovecot source, and do this myself instead of asking here

Comment: This is also called *greeting* (and learning that requires minimal effort, e.g. searching for the old value in your configuration `doveconf | grep ready`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the `login_greeting` directive in dovecot.conf, and I have set it to something other than 'Dovecot ready'.

And it works now.