# How to stop OS/daemon information leakage in dovecot (server_tokens)?

Tags: nginx, email-server, dovecot, apache2, imap

How do I stop dovecot from telling its clients what flavour of linux I'm running and that it's a dovecot imap server?

If I connect to my smtp server, I see the following snippet

```
user@host:~$ openssl s_client -crlf -connect mail.example.com:993
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot (Debian) ready.
...
user@host:~$
```

Much to my dismay, the above output clearly indicates that I'm running a Debian server and that I'm using dovecot as my IMAP server.

In nginx, you can set `server_tokens off` to disable such information leakage.

In apache, it's

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

What's the equivalent setting to tell dovecot not to leak the OS or imap server I'm running to clients?

Comment: What would the desired end result look like? Deviating from the defaults is just *adding* more information..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change dovecot's imap and pop 'banner'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1046848/how-do-i-change-dovecots-imap-and-pop-banner)

Comment: Be aware that doing this does not increase security in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the `login_greeting` option in `dovecot.conf` to the empty string

Add the following to your `dovecot.conf` file:

```
login_greeting = ''
```

Restart dovecot. Now connection attempts should look like this:

```
user@host:~$ openssl s_client -crlf -connect mail.example.com:993
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN]

...
user@host:~$
```